# Elasticsearch: aggregation and select docs only having max value of field

Tags: elasticsearch, grouping

I am using elastic search 6.5.

Basically, based on my query my index can return multiple documents, I need only those documents which has the max value for a particular field.
E.g.

```
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": { "header.date" : "2019-07-02" }
                },
                {
                    "match": { "header.field" : "ABC" }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "regexp": { "body.meta.field": "myregex1" }
                            },
                            {
                                "regexp": { "body.meta.field": "myregex2" }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
"size" : 10000
}
```

The above query will return lots of documents/messages as per the query. The sample data returned is:

```
"header" : {
            "id" : "Text_20190702101200123_111",
            "date" : "2019-07-02"
            "field": "ABC"
},
"body" : {
            "meta" : {
                "field" : "myregex1",
                "timestamp": "2019-07-02T10:12:00.123Z",
           }
}
-----------------
"header" : {
            "id" : "Text_20190702151200123_121",
            "date" : "2019-07-02"
            "field": "ABC"
},
"body" : {
            "meta" : {
                "field" : "myregex2",
                "timestamp": "2019-07-02T15:12:00.123Z",
            }
}
-----------------
"header" : {
            "id" : "Text_20190702081200133_124",
            "date" : "2019-07-02"
            "field": "ABC"
},
"body" : {
            "meta" : {
                "field" : "myregex1",
                "timestamp": "2019-07-02T08:12:00.133Z",
            }
}
```

So based on the above 3 documents, I only want the max timestamp one to be shown i.e. "timestamp": "2019-07-02T15:12:00.123Z"
I only want one document in above example.

I tried doing it as below:

```
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": { "header.date" : "2019-07-02" }
                },
                {
                    "match": { "header.field" : "ABC" }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "regexp": { "body.meta.field": "myregex1" }
                            },
                            {
                                "regexp": { "body.meta.field": "myregex2" }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
"aggs": {
    "group": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "header.id",
            "order": { "group_docs" : "desc" }
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "group_docs": { "max" : { "field": "body.meta.tiemstamp" } }
        }
    }
},

"size": "10000"
}
```

Executing the above, I am still getting all the 3 documents, instead of only one.
I do get the buckets though, but I need only one of them and not all the buckets.
The output in addition to all the records,

```
"aggregations": {
        "group": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "Text_20190702151200123_121",
                    "doc_count": 29,
                    "group_docs": {
                        "value": 1564551683867,
                        "value_as_string": "2019-07-02T15:12:00.123Z"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "Text_20190702101200123_111",
                    "doc_count": 29,
                    "group_docs": {
                        "value": 1564551633912,
                        "value_as_string": "2019-07-02T10:12:00.123Z"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "Text_20190702081200133_124",
                    "doc_count": 29,
                    "group_docs": {
                        "value": 1564510566971,
                        "value_as_string": "2019-07-02T08:12:00.133Z"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here?

*Please note that I can have more than one messages for same timestamp. So I want them all i.e. all the messages/documents belonging to the max time stamp.*

In above example there are 29 messages for same timestamp (It can go to any number). So there are 29 * 3 messages being retrieved by my query after using the above aggregation.

**Basically I am able to group correctly, I am looking for something like HAVING in SQl?**

Comment: I think you can sort by `timestamp` field in `desc` order and use `"size": 1` to limit only one document in result.

Comment: @Nishant Saini: Thank. You mean in addition to my aggregation above or only sorting? Can you please show in aggs section where to do that?

Comment: Not in aggregation, only sorting in query